# Woocommerce - How to mix products and posts on a landing page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'd like to create a landing/home page for my wordpress site that contains a woo commerce shop.   Ideally, I'd like it to be able to mix listings of products as well as blog posts by time.

EG:

SITE HEADER

PRODUCTS ADDED TODAY

POST ADDED YESTERDAY

PRODUCTS ADDED TWO DAYS AGO

POST ADDED THREE DAYS AGO

POST ADDED FOUR DAYS AGO

PRODUCTS ADDED FIVE DAYS AGO

etc.

Anybody have advice on creating this page?

Comment: There are numerous relevant questions/answers here. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => array( 'post', 'products'),                   
            'posts_per_page' => 5 
             )
$loop = new WP_query($args);
```